# How to fix height difference between Chrome and Safari?

Tags: css, safari, height, difference

I saw differences on my height's div between multiple browsers.
On Google chrome it works perfectly but on Safari, there is a difference as you can see on screenshots : 
[div-screen-chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCOst.png)

[div-screen-safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6B1OK.png)

Here is my code :

```css
.player {
        bottom: 0;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 55px;
        background-color: grey;
        color: white;
        font-family: 'Oswald';
        line-height: 50px;
    }
    
    .next-container {
        position: relative;
        float: right;
        padding-right: 10px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        font-size: 15px;
        height: 55px;
        top: -53px;
        max-width: 50%;
        min-width: 20%;
        background-color: #ffc107;
        color: white;
        line-height: 55px;
        text-align: center;
      }
```

```html
<div class="player">
  <div class="artist-title-infos">
    <span class="cover"><img class="picture" src="http://my-cover" alt="cover"></span>
    <div class="infos">
      <button class="buttonPlayer notPlaying"><i id="iconPlayer" class="fas fa-play-circle"></i></button>
      <button class="pausePlayer notPaused"><i id="iconPlayer" class="fas fa-pause-circle"></i></button>
      <span class="artist">Now : </span>
      <span class="title">Your song</span>
     </div>
    </div>
   <div class="next-container">
    <span class="next">Next : </span>
    <span class="next next-songs-0">Your song 1</span>
    <span class="next next-songs-1">, Your song 2</span>
    <span class="next next-songs-2"> & Your song 3</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

How to fix it ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you use a reset css?

Comment: A reset css ? What's that ?

Comment: The goal of a reset stylesheet is to reduce browser inconsistencies. [reset css](https://medium.com/@elad/normalize-css-or-css-reset-9d75175c5d1e)

Comment: You mean i desactivate all of css property in inspector of Chrome ?

Comment: No, read the article or try to google and you will find a lot of solution.[read](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/normalize.css)

Comment: Use height in `px` rather then `%`

Comment: I already tried but it's not working @Awais :/